# Rss-reader на java

Tags: java, rss

Подскажите с чего начать писать Rss-reader на java se?

Может посоветуете каких хороших примеров.

Comment: да тут каждую неделю вопрос про rss, xml reader

Comment: Можно поискать подходящий ридер в репозиториях типа [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [RSS feeds with Java - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/RSSFeed/article.html)
- [Reading the News with Sun's RSS Utilities](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/03/21/reading-news-with-sun-rss-utilities.html)

Начать нужно с беглого взгляда на [формат RSS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) (это разновидность XML), а затем - на уже существующие RSS-ридеры, их существует большое количество: [Open Source RSS & RDF Tools in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/rss-rdf-tools).

Answer (score 1):

Просто для развития скилов запилил на java простенький RSS reader. Может кому сгодится. За качество кода не отвечаю, но работает -  новости я отслеживаю из него.
https://github.com/rozborsky/rssReader